# Convert UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1258 using PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm needing to convert a UTF-8 character set to Windows-1252 using PHP and i'm not having much luck thus far.  My aim is to transfer text to a 3rd party system and exclude any characters not in the Windows-1252 character set.

I've tried both iconv and mb_convert_encoding but both give unexpected results.

```
$text = 'KØBENHAVN Ø ô& üü þþ';
echo iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", $text);
echo mb_convert_encoding($text, "WINDOWS-1252");
```

Output for both is 'K?BENHAVN ? ?& ?? ??'

I would not have expected the ?'s as these characters are in the WINDOWS-1252 character set.

Can anyone help cast some light on this for me please.

Comment: How are you viewing the result, in a web browser? If so is the charset of the page set to `windows-1252`?

Comment: cOle2 - I'm just running this in a terminal to test it.

    php -r 'echo iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", "KØBENHAVN Ø ô& üü þþ");'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running the text from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252 and then back from WINDOWS-1252 to UTF-8.  This gave the desire output.

```
    $text = "Ѭjanky";
    $converted =  iconv("UTF-8//IGNORE", "WINDOWS-1252//IGNORE", $text);
    $converted =  iconv("WINDOWS-1252//IGNORE", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $converted);
    echo $text; // outputs "janky"
```